# I'd like to get long url from short url on Android

Tags: java, android

I'd like to get long url from short url on Android. Is there any way to get long url?

If you can say yes. Please show me your android code.

There is a solution for C# but I can't find a way for Android.

```
string uriString = response.Headers["Location"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a field in the HTTP response headers, then yes.  Use `response.getHeader("Location");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer~ ^^;
May I ask one more~??
Can you check my code..? then tell me what point is wrong..?